# Number of VirtualBox virtual screens limited to two in contrast to other pc 4

Tags: virtualbox

The number of VirtualBox virtual screens limited to two in contrast to other pc, how to increase the limit of a number of virtual screens?

Answer (score 1):

It is dependant on the resolution the host pc uses, the internal graphics memory limit for virtualbox is 128MB and it suffices for about three 4k virtual screens and about 8 full hd 1980x1080  or cca five 2560 x 1440 virtual screen resolutions.

Edit: it automatically increases the memory limit by extending the monitors count, to 256 MB, yet it seems to be sufficing only to the values I mentioned above,
https://askubuntu.com/questions/587083/virtualbox-how-to-increase-video-memory